# Is there a way to communicate to the standard tabset component in FlexiPage to add a tab or switch a tab?

Tags: event, flexipages

Is there a way to communicate to the standard tabset component in FlexiPage to add a tab or switch a tab?

We deliver a FlexiPage as a part of a managed package. Inside that FlexiPage we provide options to customize it and add a different LWC to it. On a click of button in one LWC we would like to switch the tab in the Flexi Page or add a new tab dynamically.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is not possible.
Also it is not possible to change active tab.

If we set `activeTabValue` then the tab is not shown as selected.

However, [there is a lwc counterpart example here](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/tabset/tabset.js)
which can be used and extended to support the necessary functionality in a custom tabset component